# TableauException (204): Timeout - IPC_NamedPipe::Select(WaitForMultipleObjects)

Tags: python, tableau-api

Сode causes an error:

```
TableauException: TableauException (204): Timeout - IPC_NamedPipe::Select(WaitForMultipleObjects)
```

Snippet:

```
import dataextract as tde
tdefile = tde.Extract("test.tde")
```

How to solve a problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got this same error when trying to do a similar project using Java.

The issue for me was I was missing one of the necessary dll files in the installation directory: `metrics2.dll`

I already had a metrics2.dll file in that directory before and had decided not to overwrite it with the file provided by the Tableau SDK. Once I overwrote it, the error stopped.

If you're on Linux, the file is `libmetrics2.so`

I hope this helps you or someone else encountering this issue.

Tableau SDK for reference [here](https://onlinehelp.tableau.com/current/api/sdk/en-us/help.htm).